# Safari: input type text doesn't show full text, cursor disappears. Transform scale issue

Tags: html, css, safari, transform, scaling

I've have input type text element.
[image]

```
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name..." />
```

It doesn't show rest of text if field exceeds. I wrote "123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstxyz" and it's not showing text after `m` letter. Cursor disappears. I've this issue only on Safari 6.0 in MacOS. I'm using `transform: scale(0.7)` for my parent container div element. If I remove transform scale, it works well. So is there any way to make visible all text with keeping transform scale?

Answer (score -1):

Please try it

```
input { padding:5px; }
```